# Unexpected error: WHERE parameter "undefined" has invalid "undefined" value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, forestadmin

I’m trying to implement forest admin for one of my projects that has been developed using SQLAlchemy.
I have defined my models in the following structure:

```
SupplierCategory = sqlalchemy.Table(
    ‘supplier_category’, Base.metadata,
    Column(‘supplier_id’, UUID(as_uuid=True), sqlalchemy.ForeignKey(‘supplier.id’)),
    Column(‘category_id’, UUID(as_uuid=True), sqlalchemy.ForeignKey(‘category.id’))
)
​
class Supplier(Base):
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid4, server_default=text(‘uuid_generate_v4()’))
    name = Column(String)
    categories = relationship(“Category”, secondary=SupplierCategory, back_populates=“suppliers”)
​
class Category(Base):
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid4, server_default=text(‘uuid_generate_v4()’))
    name = Column(String)
    suppliers = relationship(“Supplier”, secondary=SupplierCategory, back_populates=“categories”)
```

When I navigate to supplier from forest admin and try to create an entry for supplier_categories, I’m facing an error saying,

`Unexpected error: WHERE parameter "undefined" has invalid "undefined" value`

I'm really not sure how to solve this problem. I really need some help here.

---

*models/supplier.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const { Sequelize } = sequelize;
  const Model = sequelize.define('supplier', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'supplier',
    underscored: true,
    schema: process.env.DATABASE_SCHEMA,
  });
​
  Model.associate = (models) => {
    Model.hasMany(models.supplier_category, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'supplier_id',
      },
      onDelete: 'cascade',
      hooks: true
    });
  };
​
  return Model;
};
```

*models/category.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const { Sequelize } = sequelize;
  const Model = sequelize.define('category', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'category',
    underscored: true,
    schema: process.env.DATABASE_SCHEMA,
  });
​
  Model.associate = (models) => {
    Model.hasMany(models.supplier_category, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'category_id',
      },
      onDelete: 'cascade',
      hooks: true
    });
  };
​
  return Model;
};
```

*models/supplier_category.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const { Sequelize } = sequelize;
  const Model = sequelize.define('supplier_category', {
  }, {
    tableName: 'supplier_category',
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: false,
    schema: process.env.DATABASE_SCHEMA,
  });
​
  Model.removeAttribute('id');
​
  Model.associate = (models) => {
    Model.belongsTo(models.supplier, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'supplier_id',
      },
      as: 'supplier',
    });
    Model.belongsTo(models.category, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'category_id',
      },
      as: 'category',
    });
  };
​
  return Model;
};
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MipJR.png)

Here is the request payload from the console that is being sent to the server:

```
{
  "data": {
    "relationships": {
      "category": {
        "data": {
          "type": "categories",
          "id": "358fedc9-05a3-4174-a6a1-501aafa750ab"
        }
      },
      "supplier": {
        "data": {
          "type": "suppliers",
          "id": "e454e11a-2afb-49b4-b163-fed7a7f54a7f"
        }
      }
    },
    "type": "supplier_categories"
  }
}
```

Server returns an error with status code 500.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The source of the error is somewhat clear: somewhere in your Javascript you're accessing a value that is `undefined`, and it ends up where it wasn't supposed to. As a side note, please avoid using other than the basic quotes (in your Python snippet).

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship between `supplier` and `category` is defined with a join table `SupplierCategory`.

Forest Admin is plugged to you SQL database and uses Express/Sequelize to provide you admin API (if you installed using Lumber).

So in your case, you'll have to use a `belongsToMany` association. See [here](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html.) for the link.

Your models should look like:

*models/supplier.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const { Sequelize } = sequelize;
  const Supplier = sequelize.define('supplier', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'supplier',
    timestamps: false,
    schema: process.env.DATABASE_SCHEMA,
  });

  Supplier.associate = (models) => {
    Supplier.belongsToMany(models.category, {
      through: models.supplier_category,
      onDelete: 'cascade',
    })
  };

  return Supplier;
};
```

*models/category.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const { Sequelize } = sequelize;
  const Category = sequelize.define('category', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'category',
    timestamps: false,
    schema: process.env.DATABASE_SCHEMA,
  });

  Category.associate = (models) => {
    Category.belongsToMany(models.supplier, {
      through: models.supplier_category,
      onDelete: 'cascade',
    })
  };

  return Category;
};
```

*models/supplier_category.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const { Sequelize } = sequelize;
  const SupplierCategory = sequelize.define('supplier_category', {
    'supplierId': {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: 'supplier_id',
    },
    'categoryId': {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: 'category_id',
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'supplier_category',
    timestamps: false,
    underscore: true,
    schema: process.env.DATABASE_SCHEMA,
  });

  SupplierCategory.associate = (models) => {
    SupplierCategory.belongsTo(models.supplier, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'supplierId',
        field: 'supplier_id',
      },
      as: 'supplier',
    });
    SupplierCategory.belongsTo(models.category, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'categoryId',
        field: 'category_id',
      },
      as: 'category',
    });
  };

  return SupplierCategory;
};
```